# How to display html5 video to cover the entire screen and play only the video visible

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want am building a mobile application with ionic, I want to display every video to cover the entire screen and also play only the video that is displaying on the screen and pause all others, the video is displaying as full screen but not playing one video at a time, Here is the code

```
<style>
        main{
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display:block;
    }
    video{        
        background-color: transparent;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:5;
        object-fit:fill;
    }
            </style>
            <main></main>   
            <script>
                let url='http://localhost/test/'
                $(document).ready(()=>{
                    $.get(url,data=>{
                        data.map(video=>$('main').append(`<video src="${url}${video.src}"></video>`))
                    })
                })
            </script>
```

Now the problem is how can i play only one video at a time, how can i play the video that is at the viewpoint, like tiktok

Comment: can you provide image visualisation for the same?

Comment: i have done that

Comment: I dont see any overlaps in the image, the only thing wrong according to me is the white area (margins) around your video, is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this awesome plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player

it should fix your problem. Good Luck!